# How to Get Original Listview Item Position from Custom Adapter Implements Filterable

Tags: android, listview

I am new at Android and want help with some Code. I have a Custom Listview Which Implements Filterable. Now What i want to do is to get Original Listview Item Position even after filtered results. For example if i have X Y and Z and i searched for Z then after filtering the position i am getting must b 2 because its starts from 0. This is my Custom Listview Class:

```
public class MyCustomfilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String>originalData = null;
private List<String>filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public MyCustomfilterAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.filteredData = data ;
    this.originalData = data ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    ViewHolder holder;

    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
    // by ListView is null.
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customfilterlistview, null);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lis2);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
    holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

This is my class where i am using this custom adapter:

```
  final MyCustomfilterAdapter adapter = new MyCustomfilterAdapter(Searchresults.this,lsts);
    search.setAdapter(adapter);


    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    search.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


           //What should i do here?
        }
    });
```

All i want to do is do get the Original listview position even after filtering my results to perform further action but i am stuck just because i have no idea how to get rid with this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead using originalData list use filteredData list in your onItemClick method. for ex String str =  filteredData.get(position);

Comment: Thanks for Reply JavaYoda. i tried this in my onclick already and i am getting Text instead of Position. Where is the problem. I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should write simple class, that has both item's name and unique position (you can use String instead of integer). For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private int originalPosition;
    public MyClass(String name, int originalPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.originalPosition = originalPosition;
    }
    private void getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    private void getPosition() {
        return this.originalPosition;
    }
}
```

Then instead of Strings, you should use your new class on adapter:

```
List<MyClass> items; // initialize somewhere
adapter = new MyCustomfilterAdapter(this, items); // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
```

Then, on click:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    MyClass item = adapter.getItem(i);
    Log.d("myapp", "item name: " + item.getName(); // writes your item's name on Log
}
```